Can there be situations where the same variable X has different values?
I often see character expressions where it is not explicitly stated what is a variable and what is a constant. If there are the same letters (e.g. $(a-b)(a-a)$) in a character expression, it makes sense to regard them as the same (e.g. $(a-b)(a-a)=0$).
Out of curiosity, are there any cases where this does not always hold depending on the problem setting (e.g. $(a-b)(a-a)=a^2-aa-ba-ba \neq 0$, this is an extreme example though)?
Obviously there are very few or no such unfriendly character settings, but I would still like to know if there are any. My questions are not based on specific books or articles originally, but on interests I have come up with.

Sometimes people may write $F(x) = \int_0^x f(x);dx$ using the symbol $x$ for two different things.  But don't do it!

You did make one mistake: $(a-b)(a-a) = a^2-a \cdot a -ba + ba = 0$ (the last plus-sign comes from "minus times minus equals plus").

Not exactly for variables, but this occurs for matrices. If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices,
$$(A+B)(A-B)= A^2-AB+BA-B^2$$
This occurs because matrix multiplication is not commutative.
As far as my highschool knowledge goes, if $AB=I$(Identity matrix), or any one of $A$ or $B$ is equal to $I$, or any one of $A$ or $B$ is equal to $O$(null matrix), then only it's commutative. Which means $-AB+AB$ should cancel out. It will be really helpful if someone with higher knowledge can provide other instances when they are commutative.

@Gwen - the question was about whether the same variable could represent different values at different places within the same context, not whether there was a way a specific example given in explanation of that question could be given an interpretation that made it true.

Mathematics is something for which we make up the rules. They are entirely under our control. If we want to study what happens if we choose a different set of rules, then we are freely able to do so. So, if you want to consider situations where variables can change their values in the middle of a calculation. all you have to do is say "this is what I am doing" and proceed to investigate it. But I can tell you now, the result will be a quick abandonment of the idea as nonsensical, as it makes deduction impossible, so there isn't much you can do. This is why you will find no mention of it.

Variables are ubiquitous in matmhematics.
There is a clear difference between an identity, like e.g. $(a^2−b^2)=(a+b)(a−b)$ and $a+0=a$, that hold for every value of $a,b$ (the formula is implicitly universally quantified) and an equation like $ax^2+bx+c=0$ that holds for some values of the variable $x$.
In this second case $a,b,c$ are parameters that are implicitly universally quantified, while the variable $x$ is not.
